# Checking out using paypal always amounts to zero

Tags: php, wordpress, paypal, woocommerce, checkout

I have an online shop, using wordpress with woocommerce.
The paypal settings is currently in sandbox mode.

The amount is correct when you go to the checkout page. But when I select the paypal checkout option, gets redirected to the paypal checkout, the amount is always zero. [Image for reference.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0RtgL.png)

Important note:
The default currency in my shop is AED - this currency is currently not supported by paypal. Thus, it needs to be converted to USD upon checking out. ( USD is the default currency in my paypal account )

How do I test if this is the cause of the problem?

EDIT: I've changed the default currency of the shop to USD but still, the checkout amount is still 0.

EDIT 2: My website does not have an SSL (http only), is that part of the issue?

Comment: Common debug procedures to try include disabling all other plugins, reverting to a default theme, and enabling [`WP_DEBUG`](https://codex.wordpress.org/WP_DEBUG) in this case specifically `WP_DEBUG_LOG` could be useful.

Answer (score 0):

You would test if the currency conversion is the problem by setting the currency in your shop to usd. If that goes well, you know the conversion is the problem, if it's still 0, something else is wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I just did what you said but still the amount is still zero upon checking out